# Factorisation of a polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and $\operatorname{char} F = p$. If $x^p - x - a$ is reducible in $F[X]$, I am to prove that the irreducible factors of the polynomial have at most degree 1. The case for $p = 2$ is easy. I have not been able to progress any further. All I know is that $F[X]$ is an Euclidean Domain, hence a PID and hence a UFD, implying that the polynomial can be written as a product of irreducible factors.

Comment: Would it help to notice that if $\alpha$ is a root so is $\alpha+1$ (and so on)?

Comment: So we will have p roots and hence we will have linear factors.

Comment: Yes, there are $p$ roots: you need to show that either there are only linera factors or it's irredcucible.

Comment: It is given that the polynomial is reducible, so defintely we will have linear factors. Thanks @ancientmathematician

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is a root we have that $(\alpha+1)^p -(\alpha+1) +a=\alpha^p+1-\alpha -1 +a=0$ as well, so that the roots of the polynomial in a splitting field are $\alpha+r$ for $r=0,1,\dots,p-1$.

Suppose then that $\phi(x)$ is an irreducible divisor of degree $s$ of our polynomial in $F[X]$. The coefficient of $-X^{s-1}$ in $\phi(X)$ is $s\alpha+t$ where $t$ is an integer; hence $s\alpha\in F$. Either $s=p$, contrary to the assumption that $X^p-X+a$ is reducible; or $\alpha\in F$. In the latter case each $X-\alpha-r\in F[X]$, and $X^p-X+a=\prod_{r=0}^{p-1}(X-\alpha-r)$.

Comment: That’s very neat!

Comment: @ancientmathematician From your earlier comment we have p roots and since the polynomial can have no more than p roots since it is of degree p, we already have p linear factors.

Comment: I am not sure that you are understanding the key point: the roots of the polynomial seem at first to be in the extension field, so that's where the linear factors lie - it may be that they group together somehow to give non-linear irreducibles over $F$ - this argument shows that can't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ be an irreducible factor of $X^p-X-a$ of degree at least $2$ and $K=F[X]/(P)$. Then we can write $K=F[b]$ as a finite field extension of $F$ with $b^p=b+a$. But if $s \in \mathbb{F}_p$, $(b+s)^p=b^p+s=(b+s)+a$, so that the $b+s$ are, in $K$, $p$ distinct roots of $X^p-X-a$. In particular, $P$ is split with simple roots in $K$.

Assume $P$ has another root $b+s_0$: then we have an $F$-morphism $\sigma: F[b] \rightarrow F[b]$ mapping $b$ to $b+s_0$. As the subset $\mathbb{Z}s_0$ of $F$ is $\mathbb{F}_p \subset F$, by considering powers of $\sigma$, we find that for each $s \in \mathbb{F}_p$, there is a power $t$ of $\sigma$ mapping $b$ to $b+s$. In particular, $P(b+s)=P(t(b))=t(P(b))=0$, so $b+s$ is a root of $P$.

So $P$ has $p$ roots but is nonzero, so it has degree $p$ and $P=X^p-X-a$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician has a much more simpler and elegant solution.

Comment: I’ve seen @ancientmathematician ‘s comment, but I can’t see why (with what they have given) the $\alpha+k$ couldn’t be roots of *different* irreducible factors of $X^p-X-a$.

Comment: @Mindlack I was keen that the OP should try to do that themselves but I've now put up the reason.