# Showing that $X^p-X-a$ is irreducible over a field of characteristic $p$ unless $a = b^p-b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field with characteristic $p$. In Milne's *Fields and Galois Theory* (page 72), it is said that the polynomial $X^p - X - a$ is irreducible in $F[X]$ unless $a = b^p - b$ for some $b \in F$.

In the latter case, $b$ would be a root of $X^p - X - a$, so it must be reducible.

Now I am working with the case where there is no such $b$. However, I really don't know how to approach this problem in the first place. For instance, I am not sure how the roots of this polynomial would look like over its splitting field.

Could you please help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: if $r$ is a root over a splitting field, consider $r+1$. (A problem much like this was on a final exam I had in a graduate course, and I didn't remember how to do it ... I will never forget....)

Comment: It’s been asked recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776491/factorisation-of-a-polynomial

Comment: @Mindlack: Not exactly the same question but it contains all elements to construct a proof via contraposition.